# Exoplayer and ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, exoplayer

I'm new to Android Studio and ExoPlayer
I started the player to play videos but I don't know to detect if the player is buffering and show a progress bar to notify the user, any help please?

Comment: [this example](https://github.com/soonsam123/UsagesOfExoplayer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soon/karat/exoplayer/complex_examples/PlayerActivity.java): listen to player states to show progressbar while buffering, possibility to change video and audio tracks, skip 10 seconds as in youtube app and much more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should implement `ExoPlayer.EventListener` and override `onPlayerStateChanged()` to detect state of playing video progress (`STATE_IDLE, STATE_BUFFERING, STATE_READY, STATE_ENDED)`

Comment: How to hide the play button when show progressBar? (like youtube)

Comment: @roghayehhosseini use a custom view for exo controller and you can hide any button which you want.

Comment: I use custom view but how do this in PlayerEventListener class?

Comment: If i want to display my progressbar outside of the PlayerView , then how to do it , please guide me

Answer (score 34):

Maybe it will be helpful to someone:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:show_buffering="true"/>
```

you can simply change XML attribute **show_buffering** if you are using Exoplayer2.

Also see [`PlayerView.setShowBuffering(PlayerView.ShowBuffering)`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#setShowBuffering-int-) for more details.

Comment: Its `app:show_buffering="always|never|when_playing"` instead of true/false

Comment: Thank you for addition, now method `setShowBuffering(boolean showBuffering)` is deprecated (since **2.9.0** version), [setShowBuffering(int showBuffering)](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#setShowBuffering-int-) is recommended, so old xml attributes don't work in latest versions

Comment: what can we use then?

Answer (score 17):

in layout file:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

in player activity:

```
player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {}

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {}

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {}

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {}

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {}

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {}
        });
```

Comment: `ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING` is deprecated use `Player.STATE_BUFFERING` instead

Comment: This helped me and also like the comment by @ShanXeeshi , ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING is deprecated, use Player.STATE_BUFFERING

Comment: How to hide the play button when show progressBar? (like youtube)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the answers of others, i did it this way. I used ExoPlayer version 2.7.0.

```
private Player.EventListener eventListener = new Player.EventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
        //Log.i(TAG,"onTracksChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
        //Log.i(TAG,"onLoadingChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        switch (playbackState) {
            case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                Log.i("EventListenerState", "Playback ended!");
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                break;
            case Player.STATE_READY:
                Log.i("EventListenerState", "Playback State Ready!");

                hideProgressBar();
                break;
            case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                Log.i("EventListenerState", "Playback buffering");
                showProgressBar();

                break;
            case Player.STATE_IDLE:

                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekProcessed() {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**mPlayer.addListener(eventListener);**

```
        Player.EventListener eventListener = new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            switch (playbackState) {
                case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                    Log.i("EventListenerState", "Playback ended!");
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekProcessed() {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `app:show_buffering="when_playing"` attr in playerView in your xml file

see this for more information https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:resize_mode="fill"
    app:surface_type="texture_view"
    app:use_controller="true"
    app:show_buffering="always" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Now Player.EventListener is deprecated, instead of use Player.Listener

```
 simpleExoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
                            override fun onTracksChanged(
                                trackGroups: TrackGroupArray,
                                trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray
                            ) {
                            }

                            override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {}
                            
                            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(
                                playWhenReady: Boolean,
                                playbackState: Int
                            ) {
                                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                                   
                                } 
                            }

                            override fun onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters: PlaybackParameters) {}
                        })
```